# Infimum of the Ky Fan metric achieved

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

We have a probability space: $ (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and random Variables $X,Y$. We define the **Ky Fan metric** as 
$$ 
d(X,Y):= \min \{\epsilon\ge 0\mid P(|X-Y|>\epsilon) \le \epsilon\}
$$

**My question:**  Why is the infimum of the Ky Fan metric achieved and so the definition well defined?

$T:=\{\epsilon\ge 0| P(|X-Y|>\epsilon) \le \epsilon\}$

I define a monoton decreasing sequence $ \epsilon_k \rightarrow d(X,Y) (k \rightarrow \infty)$  with $\epsilon_k \in T$.

$P(|X-Y|> \epsilon_k) \le \epsilon_k \le \epsilon_j$ for all $ j <k$.

For all $ j<k$ we have :

$ P(\{\omega: |X(\omega)-Y(\omega)| > \epsilon_j)\}) \le P(\{\omega:|X(\omega)-Y(\omega)| >\epsilon_k)\}\le\dots \le P(\{\omega: |X(\omega)-Y(\omega)| > d(X,Y))\})$

Comment: It may help to consider the function
$$
f_{X,Y}(\epsilon) = P(|X - Y| > \epsilon) - \epsilon
$$
or more generally,
$$
g_{X,Y}(\delta,\epsilon) = P(|X - Y| > \delta) - \epsilon
$$
It would suffice to prove that one of these functions is continuous.

Comment: $\lim_{\epsilon_k \searrow s} f_{X,Y} (\epsilon_k)= \lim_{\epsilon_k \searrow s}P(|X-Y|>\epsilon_k) - \epsilon_k = P(\bigcup_{k \ge 1} |X-Y| >\epsilon_k) -s= P(|X-Y|>s)-s$
  $\lim_{e_k  \nearrow s} f_{X,Y} (e_k)= \lim_{e_k \nearrow s}P(|X-Y|>e_k) - e_k = P(\bigcap_{k \ge 1} |X-Y| >e_k) -s= P(|X-Y|>s)-s$ 

A contious function on a compact set attain it´s infimum, but f is defined on $[0,\infty[$.

Comment: Well, consider the restriction of $f$ to $[0,1]$.  For $\epsilon > 1$, we must have $f_{X,Y}(x) < 0$.

Comment: I get it, thanks for the idea for this proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function of $\left|X-Y\right|$. With the notations of the opening post, we have for each $l$:
$$\tag{*}  1-F\left(\varepsilon_l\right)\leqslant \varepsilon_l.$$
Now, since the sequence $\left(\varepsilon_l\right)_{l\geqslant 1}$ is non-increasing, we get by right continuity of a cumulative distribution function that $\lim_{l\to  +\infty}F\left(\varepsilon_l\right)=F\left(d\left(X,Y\right)\right)$. We conclude by taking the limit as $l$ goes to infinity in (*).